# (Samba Debian x64) Server exit (multiple negprot's are not permitted)

Tags: linux, debian, samba

I just changed server and the new server causes issues, samba Always dies within seconds of using it.

Samba dies when trying to connect, sometimes instant, sometimes i get to list some folders.
I've tried to browse with windows 7 64x, windows 7 32x, and WD TV live (A standalone mediaplayer). All who ran fine with the previous server.

I had ubuntu on the previous server. With the new one i switched to Solaris for ZFS, assumed that was the issue and tried with Debian and ext4. But still the same problem, i tried several different configuration files.

This pastebin link contains some of the lines Before dying launched with 'smbd -i -F -S -d 10'
http://pastebin.com/YwbP5CUr

I've tried several configs, this was with the standard samba config without any modifications at all.

If there's any more information i can provide, please do not hesitate.

Best regards David